# Installing Custom Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am trying to install the latest (2.7.6) version of python on my ubuntu box that already has 2.7.4 installed through the package manager.  I'm up for any solution that someone has for this, but am not quite sure how to do this myself.

I have used virtualenv to create virtual python setups for different django versions, but I don't know how to use virtualenv to create an environment with an updated python version (or if it is even possible).

So to install I downloaded the source and created a custom install using the below code

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure PREFIX=$SOMEBASE/python-2.7.6
make install DESTDIR=$SOMEBASE/python-2.7.6
```

This seems to work for the installation, however when trying to install a package on python I get the error that it can't write to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  I could have it write there by running as root, but wasn't sure what that would do to my existing installation and really, really don't want to break what is already there.  So I would love to know if there is a way (and how) I could specify a location for the site-packages to be used (like $SOMEBASE/python-2.7.6/Lib/site-packages).

Comment: Here's an introduction: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/

Comment: If you can find an ubuntu package for 2.7.6 for a more recent release, then it would probably not be hard to backport it. Failing that, you could try replacing 2.7.2 with 2.7.6 in the Debian packaging for 2.7.2. You might have to adjust the patches.

Comment: Thanks Faheem, but I don't want to change the existing python, only install another one beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lennart Regebro has written [instructions on how to install easy_install, virtualenv, and pip for a particular Python installation](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/).

Alternatively, there is a shell tool called [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) which can automate much of the process. After installing python2.7.6, (and virtualenvwrapper), you'd type

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs
mkvirtualenv myenv -p /path/to/python2.7.6
```

to make a new environment called `myenv`. `mkvirtualenv` will install `easy_install` and `pip` for you. Once you activate `myenv` with

```
workon myenv
```

additional modules or packages which you install with `easy_install` or `pip` will use the right version of Python and will install the modules in `~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you rn and build Python like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/wherever/python-2.7.6
make
sudo make install
```

You'll still have to sudo when installing modules, but that's good, prevents you from doing it by mistake. They will be installed to `/wherever/python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.